# How to get point file in 5km Buffer of route generated in pgRouting?

Tags: pgrouting

I am using pgRouting to get shortest route. Now I want to get point that comes in buffer of 5km along router. Point is other shapefile. Route is using road shape so any one give me idea for same.

Comment: Are you asking how to get a buffer around the LINESTRING from the result of your shortest route query? Please consider clarifying your question.

Comment: NO i am asking how to get all places(i.e point shapefile in postgres) that comes in buffer of road(which is other shape file. So i wnat postgres query for same

Comment: @ Steve Horn may I know the answer for your words in the comment? because I am in stuck with that problem.

Answer (score 1):

Pseudocode:

```
SELECT * 
FROM points_table pt
WHERE ST_Intersects(pt.the_geom, SELECT ST_Buffer(ST_Union(w.the_geom), 5000)
                    FROM shortest_path('
                        SELECT gid as id,
                             source::integer,
                             target::integer,
                             length::double precision as cost
                            FROM ways',
                        5700, 6733, false, false) sp
                    INNER JOIN ways w
                        ON w.gid = sp.edge_id);
```

- Use PostGIS [`ST_Union`](http://postgis.refractions.net/docs/ST_Union.html) to get a LINESTRING which represents each of the line segments combined to get your route.
- [`ST_Buffer`](http://postgis.refractions.net/docs/ST_Buffer.html) will buffer the linestring 5km.
- [`ST_Intersects`](http://www.postgis.org/docs/ST_Intersects.html) retrieves all the points within the buffered zone.

Comment: Mark as answer?

Comment: Value 5000 depends totally on your shapefile vertex length columns.