# Buffer along a route

Tags: postgis, buffer, php, markers

I'm using Googlemaps service to plot some marker on the map. All markers are stored in a postgresql table, named "locations" and that has a location column (data type to geometry).
When the user clicks on the markers a route is created between them.

My question is: how can I generate a buffer (with a limit of 10km along route) and select all my locations inside the buffer. I`m really new in postgis.

P.S. This [link](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/21499/how-to-get-point-file-in-5km-buffer-of-route-generated-in-pgrouting) inspired me but without success
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT ST_Astext(geom) FROM "locations" WHERE ST_Contains( ST_Buffer( St_GeomFromText( 'LINESTRING( 6 52, 6.5 53, 7 54 )', 4326 ), 10000 ), geom )
```

- [ST_Buffer(
  geom, radius )](http://postgis.refractions.net/documentation/manual-1.4/ST_Buffer.html) creates a 10km buffer. Im using a linestring as
  example. Second argument is in meters when using SRID 4326. Calculations are in the Spatial Reference System of this Geometry.
- [ST_Contains(
  geomA, geomB )](http://postgis.refractions.net/documentation/manual-1.4/ST_Contains.html) Returns true if and only if no points of B lie in
  the exterior of A, and at least one point of the interior of B lies
  in the interior of A.

Don't hesitate to ask me if you need more help!

edit:
SRID 4326 is NOT measuring in meters ([see here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/54435/how-to-show-postgis-distance-in-meter)). 
Besides that, it's better (faster) to use [ST_DWithin](http://www.postgis.org/documentation/manual-1.5/ST_DWithin.html). There is a note in the ST_Buffer documentation:

> People often make the mistake of using this function to try to do
>   radius searches. Creating a buffer to to a radius search is slow and
>   pointless. Use ST_DWithin instead.

If you would like to measure in meters its better to use geography instead of geometry:

```
SELECT ST_Astext(geom) FROM "locations" WHERE ST_DWithin( ST_GeographyFromText( 'LINESTRING(48.85523 2.36179,48.85556 2.36205,48.85591 2.36226,48.857 2.36288,48.85806 2.36362,48.85834 2.36382,48.85818 2.36434,48.85817 2.36444,48.85817 2.36448,48.85882 2.3645,48.86 2.36454,48.86144 2.3646,48.86178 2.3646,48.86184 2.36458,48.86187 2.36455,48.86193 2.36446,48.86199 2.36455,48.86205 2.3646,48.8621 2.36464,48.86277 2.36466,48.86367 2.36469,48.86459 2.36583,48.8647 2.36577)' ), geom::geography, 10000 );
```

It transforms the points to geographic points and the input is a geographic linestring. ST_GeographyFromText() description:

> Returns a geography object from the well-known text representation.
>   SRID 4326 is assumed.

Good luck!

edit2:
If you want to extract the polygon with the buffer area u can use this query:

```
SELECT ST_Astext(geom) as "point", ST_AsText( ST_Buffer( "linestring", 10000 ) ) as "buffer" FROM "locations", ST_GeographyFromText( 'LINESTRING(48.85523
2.36179,48.85556 2.36205,48.85591 2.36226,48.857 2.36288,48.85806 2.36362,48.85834 2.36382,48.85818 2.36434,48.85817 2.36444,48.85817 2.36448,48.85882 2.3645,48.86 2.36454,48.86144 2.3646,48.86178 2.3646,48.86184 2.36458,48.86187 2.36455,48.86193 2.36446,48.86199 2.36455,48.86205 2.3646,48.8621 2.36464,48.86277 2.36466,48.86367 2.36469,48.86459 2.36583,48.8647 2.36577)' ) as "linestring" WHERE ST_DWithin("linestring", geom::geography, 10000 );
```

Comment: SELECT ST_Astext(geom) FROM "locations" WHERE ST_Contains( ST_Buffer( St_GeomFromText( 'LINESTRING(48.85523 2.36179,48.85556 2.36205,48.85591 2.36226,48.857 2.36288,48.85806 2.36362,48.85834 2.36382,48.85818 2.36434,48.85817 2.36444,48.85817 2.36448,48.85882 2.3645,48.86 2.36454,48.86144 2.3646,48.86178 2.3646,48.86184 2.36458,48.86187 2.36455,48.86193 2.36446,48.86199 2.36455,48.86205 2.3646,48.8621 2.36464,48.86277 2.36466,48.86367 2.36469,48.86459 2.36583,48.8647 2.36577)', 4326 ), 100 ), geom );to get all points along route with 100 meters buffer but it returns all my points from the table

Comment: The above query must returns ONLY 2 points.

Comment: Updated the answer, I wasn't right about SRID 4326 measurement is in meters.

Comment: I know..it`s out of the thread scope but how can I extract the polygon with the buffer area? (if I want to draw in as an  openlayer in googlemapas).

Comment: Added query in answer :)